# Pagination in HTML code embeded in PHP

Tags: php, image, pagination

I want to add pagination to the script below which searches the database and outputs the images in a folder into rows and columns. But I want the output to be in pages, not all on the same page. How can I do it?

```
<?php
    echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">';
    $getImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yaamembers");
    if(!$getImages)
        die("Cannot execute query. " . mysql_error());
    $countRows = mysql_num_rows($getImages);
    $i = 0;
    if ($countRows > 0)
    {
        while ($row_rsYaamembers = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages))
        {
            if ($i % 3 == 0) echo ($i > 0? '</tr>' : '') . '<tr>';
                echo '<td valign="top"><a target="_blank" href="yimagelarge.php?yaaid=' . $row_rsYaamembers['yaaID'] . '"><img src="/home/youngatart/yaamembers/'.$row_rsYaamembers['photo'].'" border="0" width="120" /></td>';
            if ($i == $countRows - 1)
                echo '</tr>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

I have modified the code and I get three rows of three columns of images and the last row on the page filled with one image. This is the same for all the pages generated by the pagination links. Its supposed to fill up evenly before going to the next page. What could i be doing wrong?

***Modified code below:***

```
<?Php
    $getImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yaamembers");
    if(!$getImages)
        die("Cannot execute query. " . mysql_error());

    $output = "";

    $getImages = get_images($start,$limit);
    if ($getImages && mysql_num_rows($getImages) > 0)
    {
        /* Pagination section2 */
        $getAllImages = get_images();
        $total_items = mysql_num_rows($getAllImages);
        $paginate = paginate($targetpage,$total_items,$limit,$pagenum);
        $paginate = trim($paginate);
        /* Pagination section2 End */

        echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">';
        $countRows = mysql_num_rows($getImages);
        $i = 0;
        if ($countRows > 0)
        {
            while ($row_rsYaamembers = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages))
            {
                if ($i % 3 == 0) echo ($i > 0) . '<tr>';
                    echo '<td valign="top"><a target="_blank" href="yimagelarge.php?yaaid=' . $row_rsYaamembers['yaaID'] . '"><img src="http://localhost/youngatart/yaamembers/'.$row_rsYaamembers['photo'].'" border="0" width="120" /></a><div id="text2"><div class="clear_4"></div><div align="center" id="text2"><a target="_blank" href="yimagelarge.php?yaaid=' . $row_rsYaamembers['yaaID'] . '"><div align="center" id="text2"> '.$row_rsYaamembers['school'].'</a></div><div class="clear_4"></div><div align="center" id="text2"><a target="_blank" href="yimagelarge.php?yaaid=' . $row_rsYaamembers['yaaID'] . '"> '.$row_rsYaamembers['year'].'</a></div></div></td>';
                if ($i == $countRows - 1)
                    echo '</tr>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';

        $output .= $paginate;
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: use search and you'll be surprised with what you'll find. here is so many questions and answers about pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a simple change in your script, to make it comfortable for my explanations (because I'm not a good programmer! :) ). Also, I have created some functions to work with.

Suggested changes

1. Make some changes in HTML (use div and put a CSS class, and play
   with CSS)
2. Make the `get_images` as a function

### How to use

```
function get_images($start=0,$limit=0)
{
    mysql_connect("host","user","pass")or die("Cannot connect DB");
    mysql_select_db("db_name")or die("DB does not exist");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM yaamembers";

    if($start!=0 || $limit!=0)
    {
        $sql .= " LIMIT ". $start .", ". $limit;
    }

    $sql .= ";";

    $data = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();
    return $data;
}
/* Pagination section1 */
$pagenum = 1;
$limit = 10; /* Items per page*/
$start = 0;
if(isset($_GET['pagenum'])) {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
$url = get_current_url();
$targetpage = format_url($url, "pagenum");
if($pagenum)
{
    $start = ($pagenum - 1) * $limit;
}
/* Pagination section1 End */

$output = "";

$getImages = get_images($start,$limit)
if ($getImages && mysql_num_rows($getImages) > 0)
{
    /* Pagination section2 */
    $getAllImages = get_images();
    $total_items = mysql_num_rows($getAllImages);
    $paginate = paginate($targetpage,$total_items,$limit,$pagenum);
    $paginate = trim($paginate);
    /* Pagination section2 End */

    while ($row_rsYaamembers = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages))
    {
        $output .= "
            <div>
                <a target="_blank" href="yimagelarge.php?yaaid=' . $row_rsYaamembers['yaaID'] . '">
                <img src="/home/youngatart/yaamembers/'.$row_rsYaamembers['photo'].'" border="0" width="120" />
                </a>
            </div>";
    }
    $output .= $paginate;
}
echo $output;
```

### Here follows the functions to paginate

```
<?php
    function paginate($targetpage,$total_items=0,$limit=10,$pagenum=1)
    {
        /*
        * Remember to remove pagenum variable from $targetpage variable
        */
        $adjacents = 3; /* How many items adjascent to page link */
        /* How many items to show per page $limit = 30; */

        /* Setup page vars for display. */
        if ($pagenum == 0)
            $pagenum = 1;                             /* If no page var is given, default to 1. */
        $prev = $pagenum - 1;                         /* Previous page is page - 1 */
        $next = $pagenum + 1;                         /* Next page is page + 1 */
        $lastpage = ceil($total_items/$limit);        /* Last page is equal to total pages / items per page, rounded up. */
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                        /* Last page minus 1 */
        /*
            Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object.
            We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
        */
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {
            $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
            /* previous button */
            if ($pagenum > 1)
            {
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$prev\">Previous</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">Previous</span>";
            }

            /* Pages */
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))  /* Not enough pages to bother breaking it up. */
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pagenum)
                    {
                        $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$counter\">$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    /* Enough pages to hide some */
            {
                /* Close to beginning; only hide later pages */
                if($pagenum < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $pagenum)
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$counter\">$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
                }
                /* In middle; hide some front and some back */
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $pagenum && $pagenum > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $pagenum - $adjacents; $counter <= $pagenum + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $pagenum)
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$counter\">$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";
                }
                /* close to end; only hide early pages */
                else
                {
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $pagenum)
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$counter\">$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Next button */
            if ($pagenum < $counter - 1)
            {
                $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage&pagenum=$next\">next</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
            }
            $pagination .= "</div>\n";
        }
        return $pagination;
    }

    function format_url($url, $fileds)
    {
        /*-To remove queries from URL, the field input may be single string or an array of strings. */
        $url_filed_array = explode("&",$url);
        $return_url = '';
        for($i=0; $i<count($url_filed_array); $i++)
        {
            if(is_array($fileds))
            {
                if($i==0)
                {
                    $_url = explode('?',$url_filed_array[$i]);
                    $return_url .=$_url[0] .'?';
                    $url_filed = explode('=',$_url[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $url_filed = explode('=',$url_filed_array[$i]);
                }
                if(!in_array($url_filed[0],$fileds))
                {
                    if($i==0 && isset($_url[1]))
                    {
                        $return_url .=$_url[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $return_url .=$url_filed_array[$i];
                    }
                    if(($i+1) != count($url_filed_array))
                    {
                        $return_url .="&";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($i==0)
                {
                    $_url = explode('?',$url_filed_array[$i]);
                    $return_url .=$_url[0] .'?';
                    $url_filed = explode('=',$_url[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $url_filed = explode('=',$url_filed_array[$i]);
                }
                if($url_filed[0]!=$fileds)
                {
                    if($i==0 && isset($_url[1]))
                    {
                        $return_url .=$_url[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $return_url .=$url_filed_array[$i];
                    }
                    if(($i+1) != count($url_filed_array))
                    {
                        $return_url .="&";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(substr($return_url,-1)=='&')
        {
            $return_url = substr($return_url, 0, -1);
        }
        if(substr($return_url,-1)=='?')
        {
            $return_url = substr($return_url, 0, -1);
        }
        return $return_url;
    }

    function get_current_url()
    {
        $pageURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
        {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        else
        {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
    }
?>
```

### CSS code

```
div.pagination {
    padding:3px;
    margin:3px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.pagination span.disabled ,
div.pagination span.current ,
div.pagination a
{
    background:url('../images/pagination_bg.jpg') #ffffff repeat-x right center;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    color: #6B6868;
}

div.pagination a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
    border:1px solid #f2813a;
    color: #f2813a;
    background-color: #F46F1B;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    border: 1px solid #f2813a;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    background:url('../images/pagination_bg_active.jpg') #F46F1B repeat-x right center;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    color: #ccc;
}

div.pagination span.current,
div.pagination span.disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Create two background images as you like, in folder *images*:

```
pagination_bg.jpg /* Normal button image */
pagination_bg_active.jpg /* Active or current page button image */
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm also not too vast in php. I'm abit lost. Yes please i css and cometic description. But from what i can gather, the second part i have to create on a seperate page and include it in the page for the gallery. For the first part, do i then put all these code into he part of the page i want the gallery to appear bearing in mind that i have a banner and a side section.

Comment: save the `get_images()` function from first part and ALL second part code (ie. "Paginate functions") to one file, and you can include wherever you want. You can use the code `$output=""` to `echo $output;` in gallery.php

Comment: @ Navas: Thanks. will try it out and give you an update on the outcome.

Comment: @Navas: i am getting a syntax error on this line below and i cant seem to find where the fault is. if(!$getImages) die("Cannot execute query. " . mysql_error());

Comment: @Navas: Thanks. I'm getting an error on this line, { $pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">". get_lang_word('previous') ."</span>"; }, that .get_lang_word is an undefined function. I have looked thruogh the codes and found that it has not being defined. Please what is the function of the .get_lang_word ?

Comment: @ Navas: I defined the get_lang_word as an empty function and the paggination worked. But had all the images in a single file and not in rows and columns like it was before. What function is the get_lang_word() supposed to be? And how do i get the images back into rows and columns of about 3 images per row?

Comment: @ Navas: I have done some editing and rearranging of the codes. with the arrangement, i have my images back in rows and columns but its filling up in 3 rows of 3 images, then 1 row of one image for all the pages. what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: @ Navas: I have added the modified code to initial question above for you to view. And thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @ Navas: Just Worked on it again and discovered that the items per page was set to 10. I feel so silly not taking note of that earlier. But it is well now. Thanks for all your help. Its working fine now.

Comment: sorry.. I just copied the codes from my previous work. So I forgot to replace the function get_lang_word(). I'm happy to know that Its worked fine.